# Getting a non-PIE Kitkat app to run on Marshmallow

Tags: wi-fi, compatibility

I own a Nexus 7 (2012) and it is possible with this tablet to run a software called 'bcmon' that will put the wifi chipset in monitor mode and let you inject de-auth frame to capture WPA handshakes.
This is only supposed to work on kitkat but thanks to a simple tweak I got it running on lollipop.

You can go to the [GitHub's page](https://github.com/e2002e/bcmon2020) and get the release if you own any of the devices that are supported by 'bcmon'.

Now my question is: why is this working on lollipop and not on marshmallow ?
unlegacy android is out with kernel 3.4 and it is possible to install nethunter... you see where I am going: kali linux + frame injection on native wifi card.
The issues on marshmallow is that even though 'bcmon' application runs well, the binaries that come with it run empty, no access points are detected with softwares like besside-ng or airodump.

EDIT:
Comes from the 3.4 kernel, at which point I don't know but I flashed the unlegacy one on Lollipop and the issue is the same now than with marshmallow

Comment: `bcmon` AFAIK requires a Broadcom Wifi chipset. However the Nexus 7 2012 has an AzureWave AW-NH665 (according to [iFixit teardown](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Nexus+7+Teardown/9623).

Comment: @Robert what doest AFAIK mean ?
bcmon supports the nexus 7 2012 model mobile and wifi, and it does work natively on kitkat. The link I'm giving is a version that will work also on lolllipop. But the question is about using it with marshmallow, which seems to be requiring a different approach.

Comment: May be your post is just a bit unclear. In the first sentence you claim that bcmon works on the nexus 7 2012 (if the device is in a list of supported devices I have not seen this list) but the rest of your post sounds like you never managed to start the actual binary, hence you don't really know if it works or not. Therefore I added a comment that all your effort may be useless as the Wifi chipset of the Nexus 7 is not by Broadcom, hence the chance is high that potentially bcmon will never work on this device no matter if you solve the PE problem or not.

Comment: I edited so that it can be clear. And I don't know where you have your infos online but it's wrong, it is in the list of supported devices, and the chipset you claim is not on the tablet is.